# Is it safe to take only a few bits from a number obtained with a Mersenne Twister

Tags: c, random, prng, mersenne-twister

I have to work with some code produced by an employee that is now retired, and I have some few strange things concerning random numbers. At some points, he shifted the value returned by a PRNG 10 bits to the right and then use a mask on this value.

I have already seen on the internet that some PRNG have poor randomness properties with some bits in the number they generate (like the last one, simply alternating between 1 and 0), but I've searched if some litterture existed for such problems on the Mersenne Twister, but I haven't found any. Does anyone know something about this ?

Comment: The main of this code is to generate gaussian noise, so rau is taken from a rayleigh table, the index being the shift and mask number, while teta is taken from the same random number, but this time only masked, not shifted.

Comment: in c++11, declaring a clean gaussian generator takes two lines of code. If c++11 is an option, replacing all your old, not failproof, custom generators by STL ones might be a good option.

Comment: Good to watch : http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Thanks, I'll watch that out of curiosity, but we have to keep it in C. It has been decided that keeping such things without knowing what was the idea behind it was not a good thing to do. So I'll have to modify it and write some documentation about it, to avoid such situations in the future. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, any bit should be random, this is a property of the Mersenne twister.

However (I do not know MT very deeply) you may have long-term dependence between some bits.
It is recommended to use the library functions for setting the integer range, rather than arranging the bits yourself, or you never know the complex properties it may get.

If you use the c++11 standard library, just use std::mt19937 together with std::uniform_int_distribution

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about the Mersenne Twister in particular, but what comes to mind is the typical advice one gets when trying to get a random integer in the range [0, n). If you have a PRNG returning integers with a larger range than n, you should never use modulo to reduce range like

```
x = rand() % n;
```

but ought to rescale the number

```
x = (int) floor(((double) rand()) / ((double) RAND_MAX)) * n);
```

instead. The reason is that the most significant bits of the pseudo-random number typically are more random than the lesser bits, so while the modulo operation keeps things nice and floating-point free, it also discards those precious significant bits.

While I do not know what the code you mentioned attempted to do, it might be that the shift-to-right plus masking could have been to reduce the range of the random numbers in a way that discards the least significant bits.

Comment: My guess is that he knew that he was using a PRNG with poor randomness properties on the first few bits, so he shifted that number to use the mask on the "most random" bits of the number. But it's unfortunately only a guess.

Comment: That's only the case for absolutely shitty PRNGs (which `rand()` usually is). But there the proper choice is to migrate to a better PRNG instead of polishing a turd. Even with mediocre PRNGs like Mersenne Twister, this isn't an issue.

Comment: I am just trying to help answering a question. The question being about `C` and with the other employee _retired_, the assumption that the PRNG might not be the best is valid. Regarding suggestions for updating/writing new code, I would simply suggest using a library like the GSL.

Comment: DV: With `x = rand() % n;`, `x < n`.  Yet with `x = (int) floor(((double) rand()) / ((double) RAND_MAX)) * n);`, `x <= n`.